# App icon is not visible in iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, icons

I am developing an iPhone app(not universal). Previously the app icon was visible in ipad also when I test it on iPad.
Previously it was visible also all my other app show the icon on ipad.
What could be the issue.

I added 3 icons of size - 120X120, 114X114, 57X57
and added icon in project with sizes 152X152, 76X76

[image]

Comment: Why dont you add all images Ipad setting, spot light and ipad app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See highlighted red square in bellow image.
Make icon particular size. highlighted box icon must need for set icon in. thanks.

[image: see image]

Comment: Hi, I am not able to add 114 and 57 icons, please check my edited question.

Comment: 640 * 1136 icon add please .

Answer (score 1):

See here for the correct icon sizes required:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html

If you want to support all devices, you need icons in these resolutions:
120 x 120  /  152 x 152 /  76 x 76

Comment: Where to add this man, this is an iphone project running in ipad.

Answer (score 0):

Add icon files at plist as below image. Add Icon Files and under that add icon images

[image: Names can vary]

Hope it helps you..

Comment: @SplatterStrikes try uninstalling from your iPad and reinstall again... it sounds silly but new icons will only load this way. Maybe it helps?

Answer (score 0):

When your trying to make the app images sometimes you do make a small mistake i would recommend using an os x app called prepo, just drag your image in and it will make it into an app icon, spotlight icon and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the images by clicking on the project and the scroll down to app icons and just drag and drop the icons you want to use.